# Stop current NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

Currently, I am making an `NSURLConnection` whenever `mySearchBar.text` did change. I am experiencing an issue whereby if the user enters text too quickly, The `respondData` gets corrupted.

So, I was wondering is there a way to check whether the same `NSURLConnection` is still loading? If yes, How do I drop the current connection and start a new one?

Comment: Did you try it in EDGE-Mode?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add a property for that NSURLConnection and before starting new connection, do:

```
[self.conn cancel];
self.conn = nil;
```

Comment: Also check if that is nil or not.

Comment: @PraveenS no need to check if it's nil, sending a message to nil will not hurt.

Comment: Yup there is no need but he wants to know if a connection is alive or not. Hence the nil check :-).

Comment: Yes, but he only wanted to know if it's alive to stop it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use asynchronous request. A good library for such call is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

set `[request cancel];` whenever you need to make another new request.

Comment: NSURLConnection supports asynchronous requests and has a cancel method, so ASIHTTPRequest would be a bit of overkill.