# how to stop nsurlconnection?

Tags: xcode, download, nsurlconnection

i'm using the url connection with nsfile handle to receive the data from server, 
this is the code that i use,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {

filename = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Ep1.mp4"; 

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filename contents:nil attributes:nil];
file =[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filename] ;

if (file)   {

    [file seekToEndOfFile];
}} 

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {


if (file)  { 

    [file seekToEndOfFile];

} [file writeData:data]; }


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {


[file closeFile];
}


-(void)downloadFile{

targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some url "];

DownloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:50.0];
DownloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:DownloadRequest delegate:self];

if (DownloadConnection) {
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
}
}
```

i want to stop the connection, when downloading file, so, i create the button
--->

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
DownloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: DownloadRequest delegate:self];
[ DownloadConnection cancel];   
}
```

but doesn't work, the data still receiving, did i miss understand something?
or what can i do?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229304/845115)

Answer (score 4):

**Edited :**
this is the solution that i found:

```
 - (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
DownloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: DownloadRequest delegate:self];
[ self.DownloadConnection cancel];   
}
```

add the self to cancel the current connection...